# Track model's array properties using knockout ES5

Tags: arrays, data-binding, knockout.js, knockout-es5-plugin

I have a model object in which few properties are arrays as seen below:

```
var Object1 = {
    Prop1 = [];
    Prop2 = null;
};
```

ko.track(Object1) will not track the array property Prop1. How can this array property be tracked? Currently I am doing as follows:

```
for (var property in Object1) {
      if (Array.isArray(Object1[property])) {
          //track each item in the array property
          trackModelArrayProperties(Object1[property]);
      }
  } 

 var trackModelArrayProperties = function (property) {
  var arrayPropObj = {
      property: null
  };
  ko.track(arrayPropObj );

 };
```

The above is not working because the array properties show null values after I data bind them to the input controls.

Comment: Do you have error messages? Here, [it is working](http://jsfiddle.net/ze4rb2pm/)

Comment: I cannot see any output in the result window of the link you have provided.

Comment: updated working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ze4rb2pm/1/